# Why don't these evaluate the same way?

Tags: javascript

I ran into a strange issue today and I was wondering why it was happening... I was under the impression that in javascript, anything that was not explicitly falsey (false, 0, or NULL) would return true.

When attaching console.log() to isNative in example 1 and localStorage.getItem(app + ".native_context") in example 2, both returned "false." However, when actually running these, example 1 would work in both cases, but example 2 would return true no matter what, leaving me under the impression that everything was accepted as true.

**Example 1:**

```
var isNative = localStorage.getItem(app + ".native_context");
if (isNative === "true") {
        //do x
    } else {
        //do y
    }
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
if (localStorage.getItem(app + ".native_context")) {
        //do x
    } else {
        //do y
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain what happened? I'm curious to find out.

Comment: If it contains a string `"false"` then it's a non-empty string which is truthy.

Comment: Strings aren't booleans.

Comment: We don't know what `localStorage.getItem(app + ".native_context")` evaluates to. Apparently it is not the string "true".

Comment: _isNative === "true"_ checks if `isNative` is a String exactly like "true". The examples are completely unrelated

Comment: Wow, not sure how I didn't notice that. My bad. Thanks @Juhana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most strings are "truthy" values:

```js
if('false') {
  alert('A string is usually truthy!');
}
```

Comment: I was copying the code in a different file so I didn't even notice the quotes that indicated a string, oops

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you're strictly checking for a string with value `'true'`, in the second case you're checking for any `truthy` value,

[truthy values and falsy explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)